# Watson: Valid Expression required in - Condition [Anything else] evaluated to FALSE

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

when the intent is found and not able to find any entity the below error is popped up.

How could I change the dialog system to avoid the false case.

> SpelParseException when evaluating DialogNode Id
>   [node_1_1480493211176]. Condition [Anything else] evaluated to FALSE.
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos
>   9): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the
>   expression: 'else' (and there is 1 more error in the log)

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in the condition specification. The condition should be set as `anything_else` in the dialog node editor and not `Anything else`.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add one more dialog with FALSE condition.